# HELP VS8 Command line to IDE?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, command-line, ide

PROBLEM:

C:\>**cl /LD hellomodule.c /Ic:\Python24\include c:\Python24\libs\python24.lib /link/out:hello.dll**

> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

I am using Visual Studio Prof Edi 2008.

1. What PATH should I set for this command to work?
2. How to execute above command using the IDE?

NOTE:I am studying [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C).

---

```
C:\>cl /LD hellomodule.c /Ic:\Python24\include c:\Python24\libs\python24.lib /li
nk/out:hello.dll
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>PATH="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"

C:\>cl
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>PATH="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"

C:\>cl /LD hellomodule.c /Ic:\Python24\include c:\Python24\libs\python24.lib /li
nk/out:hello.dll
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>
```

---

Comment: David, if cmeerw answered your question, you should mark it as accepted. This gives him +15  rep, and you +2 rep. Plus, it shows the your question has been fully answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set up the environment by using

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat

Answer (score 1):

Can you be a bit more specific with your question?  What exactly is not working?  Can it not find the program, does the compile fail, etc ...

The only immediate issue I can see is that the command line can't resolve the CL command.  Try including the full path to the cl.exe binary.  This is the relevant path on my machine.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe
```

**EDIT**

When using the path environment variable, you must set it to a path, not an application.  Change your path code to

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin
```

As for the inability to load mspdb80.dll, I'm worried messing with your environment variables may have contributed to this problem.  Restart your cmd.exe shell and add the line I specified above and retry.  If you still get the error with mspdb80.dll you may need to repair your Visual Studio installation.

**EDIT2**

Definitely looks like the PATH environment variable is messing up the load path for mspdb80.dll.  This thread has a bunch of solutions for this problem

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/2a3c57c5-de79-43e6-9769-35043f732d68/

Comment: @david, can you post the full command line when you qualify the path?

Comment: @JaredPar,and if I try

 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin>cl
a message box pops up that says "This application has failed to start because mspdb80.dll was not found.Re-installing the application may fix this problem."

Comment: @JaredPar,I tried PATH="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\". It pops up a box same as in above comment.

Comment: @JardPar,well .dll problem persists :) . Do I need to re-install or is there any option to repair? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JarPar,Thanks a lot.(1 up :) )

Answer (score 1):

I have a "Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt" in my Programs menu. Are you using that or the command prompt?

Comment: Don't. Use the "Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt". That's what it's for.

Comment: @John,How to start VS8 cmd prmpt? I'm noob.